# Obtener datos de un campo específico a través de una API

Tags: jquery

El objetivo es **obtener la fecha del campo name** *(se encuentra al final de este mismo campo)*, pero es que directamente me devuelve undefined y ya no se que más hacer. He probado con POSTMAN y el link funciona perfectamente, así que tiene que ser fallo de mi código.

Tengo en el código **HTML** un botón que tras ser clicado ejecuta el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>
                API Test
            </title>
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js">
                </script>
            </link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="info" type="button" value="API Test"/>
        <script src="pruebaAPI.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y el código **JQuery** se encarga de hacer la petición y mostrarla por consola:

```
$( '#info' ).on( 'click', () => {
        obtenertestApi();
    });

function testApi() {
    let headers = new Headers({
      'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    });
  
    let conf = {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: headers,
    };
    return conf;
  }

async function obtenertestApi() {

    const GET_URL = 'https://dadesobertes.gva.es/api/3/action/package_search?q=id:38e6d3ac-fd77-413e-be72-aed7fa6f13c2';

    try {

      const resultado = await fetch(
        GET_URL,
        testApi()
      );

      if (!resultado.ok) throw new Error(resultado.status);

      const json = await resultado.json();
      const datos = json;
    
      console.log(datos.name);
    
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `console.log(datos);` sin más?

Comment: La verdad que no esta claro que dato necesitas obtener, dado que dicha API no presenta un `name` en [su repuesta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZFaw.png).

Comment: @A. Cedano si, es para probar, con un console.log, del valor especifico del campo name sobra.

Comment: @Marcos por supuesto que se encuentra, si te vas a POSTMAN y haces un get por ejemplo, veras que tiene un query respecto al id, que hace referencia al último del array resources. En ese último elemento del array, se encuentra entre los distintos campos, el campo name, debajo de description. Verás que en el valor name pone algo como: COVID-19 Casos confirmados... 2021-02-15. Esa fecha que he puesto, es lo que necesito obtener de ese campo, que se encuentra al final del campo name. Si necesitas más información porque no me he explicado bien dímelo. Gracias

Comment: No. Cuando estés depurando código debes ir de lo general a lo particular. Puede que la respuesta no tenga una propiedad `name`, o puede que ni siquiera haya respuesta o que venga mal formada, etc, entonces lo propio es hacer debug de todo el elemento para revisar la respuesta completa. Eso es parte del ABC de la depuración de código.

Comment: @ShadowZ, osea que te interesa obtener el `name` del objeto con `id: 38e6d3ac....`, correcto? Si es eso, entonces solo tenes que hacer `datos.result.results[0].name`. Esto se puede ver muy fácilmente [en la imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZFaw.png) que te deje en mi comentario anterior

Comment: A ver @A. Cedano, yo cuando hago console.log(datos) así a secas, no he encontrado el valor name, pero desde POSTMAN si, por ello he preguntado. Porque no se como obtenerlo

Comment: Mi sugerencia era para que verifiques si está respondiendo y qué está respondiendo. Si responde lo esperado deberías encontrar la propiedad que buscas. Al menos en la URL sí hay varias propiedades `name`, analizando el JSON en Firefox o en una página que te muestre la estructura del JSON sabrás bajo qué propiedad exacta se encuentra el dato al que quieres acceder.

Comment: @Marcos he probado el código y en cierta parte mejor porque funciona, pero no es ese valor **name** el que necesito. El que estoy buscando se encuentra dentro de **resources**, estoy probando con el parametro resources pero nada, undefined me lanza.

Comment: @Marcos vas bien encaminado, porque datos.result.results[0].name me ha funcionado, pero como obtengo los datos dentro de resources?

Comment: Si el que buscas es este: `COVID-19 Casos confirmados por PCR+, casos PCR+ en los últimos 14 días y personas fallecidas por municipio de la Comunitat Valenciana 2021-01-04`  se encuentra en la siguiente ruta: **`resources[0].name`**

Comment: @ShadowZ, ok, tene en cuenta que `resources` es un arreglo con múltiples valores, por lo que si quiseras acceder al `name` del primero tendrias que hacerlo así: `datos.result.results[0].resources[0].name`

Comment: @A. Cedano es lo que estoy probando tanto por consola, como por POSTMAN, pero solo me devuelve undefineds

Comment: Si, perfecto era justo eso, pero una cosilla, si quiero obtener solo la fecha que se encuentra al final del name, como se puede hacer? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Entra a la URL de la API por navegador, copia el json y luego lo pegas [aquí](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#)  ahí te lo validará y además te mostrará la estructura y podrás saber cómo recorrerlo conociendo la  estructura. Firefox también tiene un buen validador de JSON incorporado, que te lo muestra identado desde la misma URL. Para leer un JSON simplemente **hay que conocer su estructura**.

Comment: @ShadowZ, intentalo, si no te sale, actualiza tu pregunta con el código y recién podemos ver como ayudarte

Comment: En el link que te pasé puedes pegar también la URL de una API cualquiera y te toma el JSON, lo valida y te muestra la estructura. Tiene herramientas para ampliarlo o minimizarlo con `+` y con `-` Esa página me ayuda mucho cuando quiero analizar cualquier JSON, sobre todo si es muy complejo. Luego, para leerlo, si los elementos son arrays tienes que recorrerlos con bucle, o acceder por el índice y si no son array, accedes directamente por su nombre de propiedad. JSON no tiene mayor misterio que ese.

Comment: Vale, ya está. Al final he aplicado `.pop()` sobre **resources** y al campo **name** un `.slice()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En JSON hay [6 tipos de datos](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/type.html), y cuando quieres acceder a cualquiera de ellos sólo tienes que **conocer la estructura del JSON** y, en base al tipo de dato, accederías al elemento que quieras usando cualquier técnica válida del lenguaje con el que estés trabajando.

Los tipos de dato son:

- Cadenas:  `"Lorem ipsum"`
- Tipos numéricos: `1`
- Objeto: `{ ... }`
- Array: `[ ... ]`
- Booleano: `TRUE` o `FALSE`
- Null: `NULL`

En casi todos los lenguajes accederías al JSON navegando entre sus nombres de claves en todos los tipos de datos, **menos en los arrays**, porque en ese caso tendrías que indicar de algún modo el índice del elemento al que quieres acceder.

En tu caso concreto, la navegación sería así:

```
data.result.results[indice].resources[indice]
```

Aquí `data` es el JSON en sí mismo, `result` contiene un objeto JSON, `results` es un array y `resources` es otro array.

Sabido eso, puedes leer tu objeto aplicando cualquier técnica. Por ejemplo, en Javascript, para acceder al último elemento de un array puedes usar `length - 1`. Vamos a probar con una muestra de tu JSON, que he traído aquí como cadena porque las reglas CORS impiden una prueba directa.

Luego, para obtener la fecha que está al final, puedes hacer un `split` del dato basándote en los espacios en blanco y acceder a la fecha usando `length - 1`. Hay otros modos de hacer esto, como usar un REGEX, pero podría ser más costoso.

```js
let str=`{"help":"https://dadesobertes.gva.es/api/3/action/help_show?name=package_search","success":true,"result":{"count":1,"sort":"score desc, metadata_modified desc","facets":{},"results":[{"geolocation":"No","license_title":"Creative Commons Attribution","relationships_as_object":[],"fecha_fin_datos":"15 febrero 2021","num_tags":5,"frequency":"bisemanal","id":"38e6d3ac-fd77-413e-be72-aed7fa6f13c2","metadata_created":"2021-01-05T11:08:28.381621","metadata_modified":"2021-02-16T16:48:22.706429","title":"COVID-19 Casos confirmados por PCR+, casos PCR+ en los \u00faltimos 14 d\u00edas y personas fallecidas por municipio de la Comunitat Valenciana 2021","state":"active","creator_user_id":"5a6a49f3-7060-4269-99eb-b788f822c898","type":"dataset","resources":[{"cache_last_updated":null,"package_id":"38e6d3ac-fd77-413e-be72-aed7fa6f13c2","datastore_active":true,"id":"c1f36903-bf2e-4a43-9cfd-5075b4a956c9","size":27186,"state":"active","archiver":"{'is_broken_printable': 'Downloaded OK', 'updated': '2021-02-17T05:36:22.175298', 'cache_filepath': u'/datos_apl/opendata/ckan/upload/resources/c1f/369/03-bf2e-4a43-9cfd-5075b4a956c9', 'last_success': '2021-02-17T05:36:22.175298', 'size': 27186L, 'is_broken': False, 'failure_count': 0, 'etag': None, 'status': 'Archived successfully', 'url_redirected_to': u'https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/38e6d3ac-fd77-413e-be72-aed7fa6f13c2/resource/c1f36903-bf2e-4a43-9cfd-5075b4a956c9/download/covid-19-casos-confirmados-por-pcr-casos-pcr-en-los-ultimos-14-dias-y-personas-fallecidas-por-mu.csv', 'hash': u'feb1e27eb90f33b9c29d93aaeddfbbd04367a6ea', 'status_id': 0, 'reason': u'', 'last_modified': None, 'resource_timestamp': '2021-02-16T11:48:52.115243', 'mimetype': u'text/csv', 'cache_url': u'https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/38e6d3ac-fd77-413e-be72-aed7fa6f13c2/resource/c1f36903-bf2e-4a43-9cfd-5075b4a956c9/download/covid-19-casos-confirmados-por-pcr-casos-pcr-en-los-ultimos-14-dias-y-personas-fallecidas-por-mu.csv', 'created': '2021-01-18T18:06:28.268826', 'first_failure': None}","hash":"","description":"COVID-19 Casos confirmados por PCR+, casos PCR+ en los \u00faltimos 14 d\u00edas y personas fallecidas por municipio de la Comunitat Valenciana 2021-01-04","format":"CSV","last_modified":"2021-01-05T16:48:02.926662","url_type":"upload","mimetype":null,"cache_url":null,"name":"COVID-19 Casos confirmados por PCR+, casos PCR+ en los \u00faltimos 14 d\u00edas y personas fallecidas por municipio de la Comunitat Valenciana 2021-01-04","created":"2021-01-05T11:08:28.797826","url":"https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/38e6d3ac-fd77-413e-be72-aed7fa6f13c2/resource/c1f36903-bf2e-4a43-9cfd-5075b4a956c9/download/covid-19-casos-confirmados-por-pcr-casos-pcr-en-los-ultimos-14-dias-y-personas-fallecidas-por-mu.csv","mimetype_inner":null,"position":0,"revision_id":"e2b1684f-17fc-4f49-8f34-13e692bbf66a","resource_type":null},{"cache_last_updated":null,"package_id":"38e6d3ac-fd77-413e-be72-aed7fa6f13c2","datastore_active":true,"id":"a6ac1919-e2ab-4103-876d-4f4f54289955","size":28049,"state":"active","archiver":"{'is_broken_printable': 'Downloaded OK', 'updated': '2021-02-17T05:36:28.485449', 'cache_filepath': u'/datos_apl/opendata/ckan/upload/resources/a6a/c19/19-e2ab-4103-876d-4f4f54289955', 'last_success': '2021-02-17T05:36:28.485449', 'size': 28049L, 'is_broken': False, 'failure_count': 0, 'etag': None, 'status': 'Archived successfully', 'url_redirected_to': u'https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/38e6d3ac-fd77-413e-be72-aed7fa6f13c2/resource/a6ac1919-e2ab-4103-876d-4f4f54289955/download/covid-19-casos-confirmados-por-pcr-casos-pcr-en-los-ultimos-14-dias-y-personas-fallecidas-por-mu.csv', 'hash': u'c9fdbdb709c56e42af716276c5cd430ff4335f4d', 'status_id': 0, 'reason': u'', 'last_modified': None, 'resource_timestamp': '2021-02-16T16:48:22.705160', 'mimetype': u'text/csv', 'cache_url': u'https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/38e6d3ac-fd77-413e-be72-aed7fa6f13c2/resource/a6ac1919-e2ab-4103-876d-4f4f54289955/download/covid-19-casos-confirmados-por-pcr-casos-pcr-en-los-ultimos-14-dias-y-personas-fallecidas-por-mu.csv', 'created': '2021-02-17T05:36:28.492313', 'first_failure': None}","hash":"","description":"COVID-19 Casos confirmados por PCR+, casos PCR+ en los \u00faltimos 14 d\u00edas y personas fallecidas por municipio de la Comunitat Valenciana 2021-02-15","format":"CSV","last_modified":"2021-02-16T16:48:22.675531","url_type":"upload","mimetype":"text/csv","cache_url":null,"name":"COVID-19 Casos confirmados por PCR+, casos PCR+ en los \u00faltimos 14 d\u00edas y personas fallecidas por municipio de la Comunitat Valenciana 2021-02-15","created":"2021-02-16T11:09:01.459281","url":"https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/38e6d3ac-fd77-413e-be72-aed7fa6f13c2/resource/a6ac1919-e2ab-4103-876d-4f4f54289955/download/covid-19-casos-confirmados-por-pcr-casos-pcr-en-los-ultimos-14-dias-y-personas-fallecidas-por-mu.csv","mimetype_inner":null,"position":12,"revision_id":"4c54efe1-5c15-4772-a633-b1f8fe9682b6","resource_type":null}]}]}}`;
let data=JSON.parse(str);
let lastObj=data.result.results[0].resources[data.result.results[0].resources.length - 1];

console.log(lastObj.name);
let arr = lastObj.name.split(" ");
let mDate=arr[arr.length-1];
console.log(mDate);
//Prueba con otra propiedad
console.log(data.result.count);
```

Al final he puesto otro ejemplo accediendo a otro dato en el JSON. En resumen, para leer un JSON sólo tienes que saber los 6 tipos de dato puede contener y conocer su estructura y en base a eso, podrás navegar por él sin ningún problema.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias @A, Cedano, me ha quedado muy claro y se entiende perfectamente la forma en lo que lo has hecho y explicado.

Comment: @ShadowZ pues ya tienes un doctorado en JSON. Teniedo claro lo dicho más arriba podrás leer sin ninguna dificultad cualquier JSON, por más complicado que parezca (por tener un estructura de muchos datos anidados unos dentro de otros). Una de las grandes ventajas de JSON es su simplicidad, porque siempre tendrás lo mismo: uno de los 6 tipos de datos y a veces dentro de un tipo otras estructuras, pero siempre con alguno de los mismos 6 tipos de datos. No hay mayor misterio.